# How to make app check if EXE Files exist in app directory?

Tags: vb.net, directory

I want my app to check for the EXE files (App1.exe, App2.exe, App3.exe ect.) while the app is in the 'splash screen' form, I currently have this code for the SplashScreen. It uses form1 for the code

````
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim splash As Splash_screen = CType(My.Application.SplashScreen, Splash_screen)
        Dim Label() As String = {"Starting Up...", "Verifying apps...", "Finalizing"}

        For i As Integer = 0 To Label.Length - 1
            splash.UpdateProgress(Label(i), CInt((i + 1) / Label.Length * 100))
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class```
````

Comment: Using `Label` as a variable name could cause confusion with the `Label` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with it. But here's some LINQ which can help perform the search

```vb
Dim fileList = {"app1.exe", "app2.exe", "app3.exe"}
Dim allFilesExist = fileList.All(Function(f) System.IO.File.Exists(f))
Dim filesWhichExist = fileList.Where(Function(f) System.IO.File.Exists(f))
Dim filesWhichDontExist = fileList.Where(Function(f) Not System.IO.File.Exists(f))
```